# IQueryable<a> to list<b> type conversion, when a & b having similar signature using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm having some basic problem with linq, I tried to google but didn't get the desired reuslt.

Lets say We have two class with almost similar signature like these:

```
public class A
    {
        public int a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
        public int c { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int x { get; set; }
        public int y { get; set; }
        public int z { get; set; }
    }
```

Here A is data context class which is generated by the framework while creating the .edmx file & B is my custom class to carry data to UI. I'm querying the data base using A & getting a iqueryable list. Now I need to convert this list into another list of type B. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `Select` to project from one type to another, then `ToList` to create a list:

```
// Property names changed to follow .NET naming conventions
var list = query.Select(a => new B { X = a.A, Y = b.B, Z = c.C })
                .ToList();
```

The compiler and runtime wouldn't care if your types had the same properties (not that they do in this case - they have different names) - they're still entirely separate types.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return the IEnumberable<A> from the method returning the EF based collection. Otherwise the assembly making the query has to be aware of the model class that will be bound to the UI?

Comment: @TGH: We don't know where this code lives, and I'm trying to avoid making any assumptions - I'm just answering the question as asked. I'm not sure where I see a significant difference between my answer and yours though - where I've got `query`, you've got a call to `SomeMethod()`... the `query` variable in my code could easily just be initialized via a call to `SomeMethod()`...

Comment: Yes, that is true. The important part is the Select(a => new).

Answer (score 2):

Assume your query method returns an `IEnumerable<A>` you can do the following.

```
IEnumerable<A> myList = SomeMethod();

var myModelList = myList.Select(a => new B(){x = a.A, y = a.B, z = a.C});
```

Answer (score 2):

You will use projections when selecting.

```
var myQuery = (from a in context.A
              select new B{
                  x = a.A,
                  y = a.B,
                  z = a.C
               });

return myQuery.ToList();
```